# Javascript getUTCMonth() returns 0 for December?

Tags: javascript

My fiddle here is returning 0 for December

https://jsfiddle.net/3CpXz/

```
var exploded = "2011-12-25".split('-');
var d = new Date(exploded[0], exploded[1], exploded[2]);
document.write("year"+d.getUTCFullYear()+ " month"+d.getUTCMonth()+" day"+d.getUTCDate());
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, this is the other way around: **you are defining date as if it was in January**.

See [the documentation on `Date()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date):

> **month** - Integer value representing the month, **beginning with 0** for January to 11 for December.

You provided `12`, so it was treated as `0` (January).

If you need a **proof**, see [modified version of the script, showing the whole date and time](http://jsfiddle.net/3CpXz/1/).

Comment: Thanks!!! OMG I am a retard, also, I've noticed its ouputting the 24th rather than the 25th is that cause the timestamp is 00:00 ?

Comment: @Baconbeastnz: I believe this specific issue is a result of the following: you are creating date as it is was local time, but you are outputting UTC day. See [detailed result for both UTC and local time with hours included](http://jsfiddle.net/3CpXz/12/). Did it help?

Comment: @Baconbeastnz: Basically you are somewhere in the eastern hemisphere and because of that UTC time is actually earlier (if you could say that).

Comment: What asshole decided on making month null based while the rest of the world calls January the 1st month... Just lazy? or deliberately wanted to create confusion / bugs.. Thanks for the clarification  :-)

Answer (score 8):

Did you notice that it prints `2012` for the year? The problem is that it uses a 0-based month, so it thinks month 12 of this year is actually the 0th month of next year. In other words, 0 is January and 11 is December, so 12 is next January.

You need to subtract 1 from the human-readable month:

```
var d = new Date(exploded[0], exploded[1] - 1, exploded[2]);
```

If I change the program to this:

```
var exploded = "2011-12-25".split('-');
var d = new Date(exploded[0], exploded[1] - 1, exploded[2]);
document.write(d.toString());
```

It prints: `Sun Dec 25 00:00:00 EST 2011`

Comment: thats returning year2011 month11 day24 which is erroneous aswell :/

Comment: infact if i modify it  http://jsfiddle.net/3CpXz/  , even just toString() is failing

Comment: @Baconbeastnz That's because `getUTCMonth` is also 0-11. Try: `" month"+(d.getUTCMonth()+1)`

Comment: You should be getting `year2011 month11 day25`.

Comment: I am going to upvote your answer, as you are pinpointing the same issue as my answer. +1

Answer (score 2):

December is 11 in the Date Object. You'll have to subtract 1 to make it 0-indexed.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getutcmonth.asp

Comment: I would upvote your answer, as it points OP to the right direction (as @Gabe's answer and mine), but I will not do it because of the source of information you referenced. Please see [W3Fools.com](http://w3fools.com/) for detailed explanation and reasons.

Comment: No, it is not, I believe :) See [Date object docs](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp) and [JS Date object tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_date.asp) - **none** of them actually mentions that `new Date()` should be given number of the month beginning with `0` for January (and `11` for December). Link you have provided mentions only correct values for `getUTCMonth()`, not for the constructor of Date object. That link even has `var month=new Array(12);` in its example, which is not a good practice. W3Schools are full of inaccuracies :(