# How to get number of days in a month excluding weekends

Tags: javascript

I have written a function to give me all days of a month excluding weekends. Every thing works fine but when I want to get December days the Date object returns 01 Jan of next week and the function returns an empty array.

Any help please.

```
function getDaysInMonth(month, year) {
    var date = new Date(year, month-1, 1);
    var days = [];
    while (date.getMonth() === month) {

        // Exclude weekends
        var tmpDate = new Date(date);            
        var weekDay = tmpDate.getDay(); // week day
        var day = tmpDate.getDate(); // day

        if (weekDay !== 1 && weekDay !== 2) {
            days.push(day);
        }

        date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
    }

    return days;
}  

alert(getDaysInMonth(month, year))
```

Comment: `date.getMonth() === month` ... getMOnth returns 0 to 11 but you've called the function with month === 12 ... you obviously know that you have to subrtract one from the month :p

Comment: also, weekends are where getDay() == 6 or getDay() == 0

Comment: @isherwood - yes, they do

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript getUTCMonth() returns 0 for December?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8335276/javascript-getutcmonth-returns-0-for-december)

Comment: @Blazemonger - close, but not really

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you create a date, you use month = 0 to 11

This also goes for when you GET the month - it also returns 0 to 11

I'm surprised you said

> Every thing works fine

It actually never worked for any month - always would return an empty array

```
function getDaysInMonth(month, year) {
    month--; // lets fix the month once, here and be done with it
    var date = new Date(year, month, 1);
    var days = [];
    while (date.getMonth() === month) {

        // Exclude weekends
        var tmpDate = new Date(date);            
        var weekDay = tmpDate.getDay(); // week day
        var day = tmpDate.getDate(); // day

        if (weekDay%6) { // exclude 0=Sunday and 6=Saturday
            days.push(day);
        }

        date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
    }

    return days;
}  

alert(getDaysInMonth(month, year))
```

Comment: Sort of? this does 100% what you intended :p

Comment: If you do this on my script `var date = new Date(year, month, 1);`  it's fine. It works for all months not Dec

Comment: your script doesn't do that ... look, there's a month-1, not a month ... this might explain why you thought the weekend was on monday (1) and tuesday(2)

Comment: try what you think is your working code with march 2016 - why no march 31?

Comment: also, your script (as posted in the question) always returns an empty array - it has to, because the month never matches

Comment: Thanks a lot is exactly what I was searching for.