# Take only the days of the month by removing Saturday and Sunday

Tags: javascript, typescript

How can I add only the days of the month in an array removing Saturday and Sunday?

user goes set the month and year and with this month I get the days.

ex:

March 2018

1 2 5 6 7 8 9 12 13 14 15 16 19 20 21 22 23 26 27 28 29 30

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get days in a month excluding weekends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39296064/how-to-get-days-in-a-month-excluding-weekends)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using the `getDay` method of the `Date` object, with the note that `0` and `6` represent Sunday and Saturday respectively. So with that, just iterate through all the days of the month, and exclude those which are a weekend day:

```js
// March 2018
// March -> 2 (months are zero-indexed)

function getWeekdaysInMonth(year, month) {
    const days = [];

    let date = new Date(year, month, 1);
    while (date.getMonth() === month) {
        if (![0, 6].includes(date.getDay())) days.push(date.getDate());
        date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
    }
    
    return days;
}

console.log(getWeekdaysInMonth(2018, 2));
```

That function should work for any year and month.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you have a year, a month and the days (dates) of this month:

```
const y = 2018
const m = 2 //(0 based)
const days = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7...]
```

now you can map the array of days into date objects:

```
const dates = days.map(day => new Date(y, m, day))
```

now you can filter the dates using `getDay()` which returns day of the week (0 based)

```
const filteredDates = dates.filter(date => date.getDay() !== 0 && date.getDay() !== 6)
```

now you can map the dates back to the day of the month

```
const filteredDays = filteredDates.map(date => date.getDate())
```

BTW, you can write all of this in a one liner:

```
const noSundaySaturday = (year, month, daysArray) =>
                    daysArray
                       .map(day => new Date(year, month, day))
                       .filter(date => date.getDay() !== 0 && date.getDay() !== 6)
                       .map(date => date.getDate())
```

Answer (score 0):

Filter the array of dates based on the predicate which asks if the day is not Saturday (6) or Sunday (0).

```
const dates = allDates.filter(date => date.getDay() != 6 && date.getDay() != 0)
```